# Limit each line in text file to X amount of words

Tags: vb.net, text, line, limit, words

Hi I am trying to make a program with VB.NET that opens a text file, capitalizes the first letter of each line, limits each line to 7 **words** or less, and then puts each line into a list box. For example it would take a string of text like this:

- w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 w6 w7 w8 w9 w10 w11 w12 w13 w14

and turn it into two separate lines like this:

- W1 w2 w3 w4 w5 w6 w7
- W8 w9 w10 w11 w12 w13 w14

This is the code I have right now to read each line and capitalize the first letter of the line into the list box

```
Try
        Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(filePath)

        Dim textLine As String = ""

        Do While reader.Peek <> -1

            textLine = reader.ReadLine

            textLine = textLine.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper + textLine.Substring(1)

            MAIN_FORM.previewBox.Items.Add(textLine)

        Loop

        reader.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Now I just need to figure out how to break each line into 7 words or less.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of Linq could help a lot....

```
Dim count As Integer = 7
Dim pos As Integer = 0
Do While reader.Peek <> -1

    textLine = reader.ReadLine

    ' Split the line to the individual words
    Dim parts = textLine.Split(" "c)
    do
        ' Skip the previous words and take the count required
        Dim block = parts.Skip(pos).Take(count).ToArray()

        ' position to read the next count words
        pos = pos + count

        if block.Count > 0 Then
            block(0) = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(block(0))
        end if
        MAIN_FORM.previewBox.Items.Add(string.Join(" ", block))
   Loop While(pos < parts.Length)
Loop
```

**EDIT:** Not sure to have tested every edge case, but this should work for any length

Comment: Almost there but it doesn't seem to cater for the possibility of having 15+ words on an input line. Probably just needs an inner loop keep breaking down `last` until there is nothing left.

Comment: I am curious what does the **c** mean in the line "Dim parts = textLine.Split(" "c)? Was that a typo or is that supposed to be there for some reason?

Comment: Signals the Split function to use the overload that takes a single character

Comment: String.Split wants a ParamArray of strings or Chars as its first argument. Forcing the " "c means that you want to pass a single char. Because the split receives a ParamArray I can avoid to explicitly build a char array to pass a single char (see the examples in VB.NET section of [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. I appreciated you giving me the code that worked I just wanted to try and understand why it worked.

Comment: Hey Steve sorry to bug you again but I actually have a slight tweak that I would like to do. I would like it to limit each line to 7 words  **OR** go to a new line if there is a punctuation mark like a period or an exclamation point. Any idea how I could tweak it to do that?

Comment: Check the contents of the elements in the variable block and if you find your chars take the elements before transforming them in a new string to add at your list box. However I suggest to post a new question because you could find more people to look at your problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49689/discussion-between-slister-and-steve)